# Updating text of a label

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If rdorooms.Checked = True And chkgroup.Checked = True Then
        price = 32.5
        lblmessage.Text = lblmessage.Text & price
    ElseIf rdorooms.Checked = True Then
        price = nudpeople.Value * 10
        lblmessage.Text = lblmessage.Text & price
    End If
End Sub
```

After I click Button1 the lblmessage will show me what I need but when I click it again it shows the previous result added to it the current result.

So, for example,
lblmessage = 32.5
then click again
lblmessage = 32.532.5
and so on

I don't want that to happen.

Comment: `lblMessage.Text = price` is what you're looking for. If you have text that should be included such as `"Price: 32.53"` then you'll need to add that there such as `lblMessage.Text = "Price: " & price`.

Comment: I see that is a proper solution but is this way I cannot display the previous content of lblmessage.

So in this case would I have to create another variable to store the content so it doesn't get conflicted with the price and lblmessage ??

Comment: What are you wanting to display? Please give a proper example so that we can help you more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out from what u said firstly.

Comment: than @PerpetualJ should give the answer and you should accept it as answer instead of write our own answer. Is is a bad style to do it other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If rdorooms.Checked = True And chkgroup.Checked = True Then
        price = 32.5

    ElseIf rdorooms.Checked = True Then
        price = nudpeople.Value * 10

    End If
    lblmessage.Text = price

End Sub
```